# FontForge: Lost access to `Metrics` → `Set Width…`

Tags: font-forge

I was editing a bitmap font in FontForge (via a single default 12 pt bitmap strike). At some point, I lost the ability to change the widths of characters using `Metrics` → `Set Width…`, either in the character map or character editor dialogs.

Glyphs already drawn retain the previous widths. Empty glyph slots now default to a large width like 1000 that cannot be changed.

It's unclear what action caused this. One candidate is that I highlighted some characters in the character map (like À etc.) and typed `ctl`+`shift`+`B` to automatically build some empty accented characters. I can confirm that only a handful of characters were highlighted at the time.

The issue appears to affect the saved font as well, and I cannot repair it by exiting and re-starting the program.

What's going on here? Is this a feature, or a bug? How do I regain the ability to set the widths of individual glyph bitmaps?

I installed fontforge from the Ubuntu repositories, here is the output of `fontforge --version`:

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2022. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Version: 20201107
 Based on sources from 2022-01-13 19:13 UTC-ML-D-GDK3.
PythonUI_Init()
copyUIMethodsToBaseTable()
fontforge 20201107
build date: 2022-01-13 19:13 UTC
```